# How to specify the repository url of a local repository in a package.json for NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a nodejs project that's located on a server within my local network.

I can successfully install the package named 'foo' with npm with

```
npm install git+ssh://gitolite@my.server:my/project
```

But whenever I try to update the package with

```
npm update foo
```

nothing happens.

My first thought was I have to specify the correct url in my package.json like this:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+ssh://gitolite@my.server:my/project"
    }
    [...]
}
```

But this does not work. The update command always looks up the npm repository:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/foo
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/foo
```

How can I make npm recognize the correct local url?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a problem with the local git url per se. Rather, I think it's due to npm in general not updating git repo's when doing "npm update". See https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/1727 . See also https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2419 .

Answer (score 2):

For private repository you have to put it under dependencies.

```
{
    "private": true
    "name": "foo",
    "dependencies": {
        "private-repo": "git+ssh://gitolite@my.server:my/project",
    }
    [...]
}
```

Setting `private` to true will prevent npm from publishing.

Comment: `private: true` is out-dated right?